# Is there a way to substitute the JPopup Component for JMenu with a different component?

Tags: java, swing

I have a custom Popup widget and I want to swap the JPopup component in JMenu with this. Is there any way to achieve this?

EDIT 1: Tried to implement it with JMenuItem
Adapted from [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/PopupMenuDemoProject/src/components/PopupMenuDemo.java)

```
    // When I create the menu item
    MyMenuItem m = new MyMenuItem("Exit");
    MouseListener popUp = new PopupListener();
    m.addMouseListener(popUp);

    // The PopupListener class
    class PopupListener extends MouseAdapter {
            MyPopup popup;
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                maybeShowPopup(e);
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                maybeShowPopup(e);
            }

            private void maybeShowPopup(MouseEvent e) {
                if(e.getComponent() instanceof MyMenuItem){
                    ((MyMenuItem) e.getComponent()).showMyPopupMenu();
                    e.getComponent().setVisible(true);
                    e.getComponent().requestFocus();
                }
            }
        }

// MyMenuItem code
public class MyMenuItem extends JMenuItem {

        private MyPopup popup;
        MyMenuItem(String s){
            super(s);
            popup = new MyPopup();
        }

        public JMenuItem add(JMenuItem menuItem){
            return popup.add(menuItem);
        }

        @Override
        public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
            super.setLocation(x,y);
        }

        public void showMyPopupMenu(){
            popup.show(this.getParent(), (int)getX(), (int)getY());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which part do you want to swap ? `JPopupMenu popupMenu` in [JMenu](https://github.com/Himansu-Nayak/java7-sourcecode/blob/master/javax/swing/JMenu.java). If so, you can see in the source code that it is private, so I guess you'll have to extend `JMenuItem`.

Comment: So, I tried to extend the JMenuItem and added my custom popup menu in it. Then I added a MouseListener to the JMenuItem so when it's clicked I get the popup to show. However, the popup shows but the JMenuItem disappears. Is there any way to keep the JMenuItem visible? I've looked around SO, but using e.consume() or setVisible(true) on JMenuItem doesn't work. I'll add the code to the question too.

Comment: I would copy `JMenu` source and modify it. For more help post [mcve] reproducing the problem

Comment: Thanks Added some more code. Hope it helps. Will try to do as you suggested.